# Facing problem as Android build failed in a react native expo app due to unknown error

Tags: react-native, android-build, react-android

[I'm facing this issue while i'm trying to create build for my react native expo app,I have removed not usesful packages and dependecies from my app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxFXp.png)

I have used the command
"npx eas build --platform android"
and it was not showing any error but after 5-6 mins the process just stopped and shown  this error
[message after build failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U0RU.png)

No such error was showing while running on the expo go app or on the android emulator
,the app is running perfectly wihtout showing any error but don't know why this is happening while creating  build for the app.

Please help me regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `./gradlew clean` in your terminal inside the android folder. And see what error you get there. If the error remains the same, try executing this command `gradlew --scan assembleRelease`. Feel free to post errors on here and ask for more help!

Comment: As my app is a react native expo app it does not have any folder named android, then what should I do .

Comment: Look into expo prebuilding

Comment: Another great feature you should try is `npx expo run:android` this makes a development build without using the `Expo Application Service` and gives possible errors